# How to import shared service dependency in shared module in angular?

Tags: angular, architecture, primeng, angular-module

we are in process of developing base level architecture for our Angular 5 application. We are highly using **Feature module** to import shared and other business module in app.module in order to minimize number of line in app.module.

> We supposed to create independent, detachable reusable component and
>   import them first into shared module and then after in app.module via
>   shared module.

For this we are following strict folder structure of creating `.module` file for every component.But, we have encountered in situation where we are using some service as reusable in entire application like `message service` and there are some module and service are required for this which We should be importing in component module file, but as it reusable service we have created only on service file and importing it in shared.module file as provider and the necessary module and service are importing in `app.module` file.

We are trying to find way to import all necessary module and service for `message service` in his own module file or `shared.module` file, but not going through it.

**Note** - We are trying to use `PrimeNg` message component - [Messages](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/messages)

Comment: The dependency should be specified in `imports`, generally it's as simple as that. What exactly did you try, and what did go wrong?

Comment: I tried adding this dependency in `shared.module`, it didn't work. Work with `app.module`. Reusable component should not depend on `app.module` for this.

Comment: What did exactly not work? What was the error? Please, post http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with your current attempt and clear problem statement.